# How can I take precise control over the size of caption text of images?

Tags: captions

In the caption of the images of my text, the size of the text "Figure 1.1" (and so) is greater than the text itself.

The result is
[image]

How can I take precise control over this text?

The code is

```
\hvFloat[%
floatPos=htb,%
capWidth=0.40,%
capPos=r,%
capVPos=b,%
objectPos=l,%
%framedObject=true,%
]{figure}{\includegraphics[scale=1]{pascalina_ThomasWatson.jpg}}[Lorem ipsum]{\scriptsize \sffamily Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit.}.}
```

Comment: where does the command `hvFloat` come from? Can you extend your example to a [compilable minimal working example](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/html/)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want complete control of your caption, use `\captionsetup` from the `caption` package which is loaded by `hvfloat`.

If you want to change the font of the caption altogether act on the key `font` while if you want to change the font of the caption label act on the key `labelfont`.

For example, if you want everything in `\scriptsize` and `\sffamily` issue the command

```
\captionsetup[figure]{font={scriptsize,sf}}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{hvfloat}
\captionsetup[figure]{font={scriptsize,sf}}

\begin{document}

\hvFloat[%
floatPos=htb,%
capWidth=0.40,%
capPos=r,%
capVPos=b,%
objectPos=l,%
%framedObject=true,%
]{figure}{\includegraphics[scale=1]{pascalina_ThomasWatson.jpg}}[Lorem ipsum]{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit.}{fig:fig}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your solution is simple, elegant, and works!.

Comment: And my code will be simplified, too.

Comment: @karloswitt Happy it helped!

Answer (score 6):

`hvfloat` itself loads package `caption` by default. So you can set all optional arguments provided by `caption`, eg:

```
\usepackage{hvfloat}
\captionsetup{labelfont=sf}
```

Comment: Your answer solves the font, but no the size. 
In any case, it is useful.

Comment: I gave an example for the setting. It should not be too difficult to add `small` to the setup!

Comment: I will leave in my toolbox.

Comment: You could simply comment on my answer instead of providing another one. Anyway, +1 to you.